# Running 32 bit exe on Ubuntu :libudev.so : cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, ubuntu-12.04, 32bit-64bit, i386

I am trying to run an exe which uses `libudev.so` but it gives this error :

> error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Running `uname -a` gives :

> 3.5.0-44-generic #67~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 13 16:16:57 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I am using **Ubuntu 12.04**

I have checked `/lib` `/lib32` `/lib64` there is no libudev in there 
but in Synaptic manager I can see `libudev0` installed (see image below)

[image: libudev on Synaptic Manager]
and I could find it in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0`.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Is your 'exe' 32-bit or 64-bit? Try `file my.exe`. If it's a 32-bit executable, it's expected that a 64-bit library is not used for it (then you need to set up a "multiarch" system and install `libudev0:i386` with all its dependencies)

Comment: file my.exe gives :  ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0xe561272b6fba244041101a89deb43b9cdf17fe3a, not stripped , Its a 32 bit exe , I will install what you said and try .

Comment: Yes, that's it. If your system is not "multiarch" yet (you know it when package `libudev0:i386` is not found), you may need to configure it. It's done with `dpkg --add-architecture i386` on debian (then `apt-get update`), but it may be different in Ubuntu.

Comment: libudev0:i386 is installed so I guess its a multiarch!

Comment: I have found running a 32 bit exe on Ubuntu we need to install all the dependecies related to 32 bit only.FOr example after installing libudev0:i386  , I ran the app again and got error stating not able to find libQtGui4.so.4 not found , I installed again the i386 version libQtGui4.so (libQtGui4:i386) and app worked.

Comment: or better install ia32-libs!

Comment: You can always use `ldd ./my.exe` and see which libraries are missing (then `apt-get install apt-file; apt-file update; apt-file search libSomething.so.42` to know missing packages). @Raulp: it's not that better because it installs a somewhat arbitrary set of "everyday use" libraries, and there's no guarantee that the application doesn't need something extra. `ia32-libs` is obsolete on modern multiarch debian-based distros.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko: I agree.Thanks for the info!You can paste your explanation in the answer tab!

Comment: yep, posted as an answer (putting all info scattered in my comments together).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out (as I suspected) that you tried to run a 32-bit executable on a 64-bit system. 64-bit Linux kernel is capable of running 32-bit executables (that's why you don't get "exec format error"), but it needs a separate set of (32-bit) libraries: 64-bit version of `libudev.so.0` is useless for a 32-bit program. (See [ld.so manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld.so) for some details on shared library dependency resolution).

Modern Debian-based distributions support simultaneous library installation for several architectures. `apt-get install libudev0:i386` should get a 32-bit version of the library and all its dependencies (there might be plenty of them if it's the first time you use a 32-bit application). If you upgraded from an ancient installation, you might need to add `i386` to architectures supported by `dpkg`, like this:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Some advices to use if the program needs some other libraries as well:

- Use [ldd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ldd) to see all the dependencies at once (and what's missing)
- Install [apt-file](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/apt-file.1.html) and run `apt-file update`, so you can look up a package name by a file name, even if the package is not currently installed (like this: `apt-file search /libudev.so.0`)

There was also an old Debian way of getting 32-bit libraries on a 64-bit system: `ia32-libs` package in amd64 repositories provided a set of libraries, conceptually "everything your application might need". *Don't use this approach* unless you're running Debian squeeze or earlier (or a debian-based distro of the same age). Even when it worked, there was no guarantee that the program doesn't need some other library as well. `Ia32-libs` was useful when multiarch support was not ready yet, and that was some years ago.

Answer (score 7):

I just followed this instructions and it works just fine.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/369310/how-to-fix-missing-libudev-so-0-for-chrome-to-start-again

```
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.3.5 /usr/lib/libudev.so.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Try creating symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0
```

Comment: Just in case somebody wold need it, in my case (a different rpm...), for Rosa Linux, it was sudo ln -sf /lib/libudev.so.1 /lib/libudev.so.0

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error while messing around with Orange Pi RK3399 trying to flash firmware from Linux Mint. The solution was in manual for this Pi and given the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core gitk git-gui gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf u-boot-tools device-tree-compiler gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu mtools parted libudev-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev libssl-dev pv e2fsprogs build-essential fakeroot devscripts
```

Not sure but `libudev-dev` should be enough so the command would be:

```
sudo apt-get install libudev-dev
```

Not all those given packages are needed.